# A morphism of sheaves is surjective if it is surjective at the level of stalk for every point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I would like to show that if $\phi:\mathscr{F} \rightarrow \mathscr{G}$ be a morphism of sheaves (on a topological space $X$) such that $\phi_P:\mathscr{F}_{P} \rightarrow \mathscr{G}_{P}$ is surjective for all $P \in X$ then $\phi$ is also surjective.

My effort: I am using the fact $\text{Im}(\phi)_P=\text{Im}(\phi_P)$ for all $P \in X$. Then we have $\text{Im}(\phi)_P=\mathscr{G}_P$ implying that $(\mathscr{G}/\text{Im}(\phi))_P=\mathscr{G}_P/\text{Im}(\phi)_P=0$. Now since $\mathscr{G}/\text{Im}(\phi)$ is a sheaf we've $\mathscr{G}/\text{Im}(\phi)=0$. From here how do I conclude that $\text{Im}(\phi)=\mathscr{G}$.

I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $im(\phi) = \mathscr G$ I will assume you mean that the canonical map $im(\phi) \longrightarrow \mathscr G$ is an isomorphism. This argument holds in any abelian category.

As you have proven, $\mathscr G/im(\phi) = 0$. This is precisely the cokernel of $\phi$, and the image of a map in an abelian category is defined to be the kernel of its cokernel. We have the following universal property:

[image: kernel diagram]

In symbols, $\pi \circ \psi = 0$ implies the existence and uniqueness of the dashed map making the diagram commute.

Now, as we said, $im(\phi) = ker(cok(\phi))=ker(\pi)$. So by "the canonical map $im(\phi) \longrightarrow \mathscr G$", I mean $\iota$. We will proceed to show that it is an isomorphism.

Since $\mathscr G/im(\phi)=0$, we necessarily have $\pi = 0$. We will therefore show that $id: \mathscr G \longrightarrow \mathscr G$ satisfies the universal property of $ker(\pi)$. Indeed, let $\psi: \mathscr H \longrightarrow \mathscr G$ satisfy $\pi \circ \psi = 0 \circ \psi$. Thus, we have the commutative diagram:

[image: identity kernel diagram]

and certainly, only $\psi$ can fill in for the dashed map and allow the diagram to commute. Hence, this satisfies the same universal property as $ker(\pi)$. Hence, they are isomorphic. This arises by applying the universal property in both directions. In fact, this yields the following commutative diagram.

[image: iso!]

Hence, we have shown that the canonical map $im(\phi)=ker(\pi)\longrightarrow \mathscr G$ is an isomorphism. This is the closest to equality we can get in an abelian category.